# Casting an object literal as a function parameter to a type with full type checking in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of JavaScript code someone wrote that I'm converting to typescript. I have lots of code like this

```
const shapes = [];

shapes.push({ name: 'Circle', radius: 12 });
shapes.push({ name: 'Rectangle', width: 34, height: 56 });
...
```

I want to make this more type safe so I've added

```
interface Shape {
   name: string;
}

interface Circle extends Shape {
   radius: number;
}

interface Rectangle extends Shape {
   width: number;
   height: number;
}
```

Now, I want to fix the code to be more type checked. My first attempt was this

```
const shapes: Shape[] = [];

shapes.push({ name: 'Circle', radius: 12 } as Circle);
shapes.push({ name: 'Rectangle', width: 34, height: 56 } as Rectangle);
...
```

The problem is, this `as Type` syntax is not actually fully type checking. The following line passes even though the required 'height' property is missing

```
shapes.push({ name: 'Rectangle', width: 34 } as Rectangle);
```

I can fix it by moving the creation outside the function call

```
const r: Rectangle = { name: 'Rectangle', width: 34 };  // ERROR: missing height (Yay!)
shapes.push(r);
```

But, it makes the code really ugly given the long list of shapes.

Is there some other way than `as Type` to *cast* an object literal to a type inline as a parameter to a function that will do full type checking?

PS: I'm not looking for a way to refactor the code (like shape constructors/factories). I'm just asking the previous question *"Is there some other way than `as Type` to *cast* an object literal to a type inline as a parameter to a function that will do full type checking?"*  My actual code is nothing like this but I needed to make a small example to demo the issue

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAs4AcUG8CwAUMiciHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcRAvkUaJLIigDCwKAgA2KCAA9IIACZ00mHMgLFSUOHOABXOrRA6KAI2jtCXQj3DR4SZACUICMHBDMJyabIVLseIlJkAHdgOTB0AyNTKHMg9AhgZnQwKJMzTm5CGB0QF2AAexBkSAYACgBKVUDSBCKGemUIfT8cAG0AXWQAXmRO8xqSAHohkIKoAGtFMpACsGAkRU1tPWRgRQp1uhYKwer1IJI6kAaEWmFRT161Q9uyShpkAHIEEXEIJ4AaPaCOOLu6E06AA6LB6dBlBAVf4kSx7EbIeDAMTTOQFZogJ5gMhzBYoZa6RTrZCbOjbdy7A77O6NfwgsGAso3GmkchUWgvN4SL4-UgcZBwRQXd6U35ZIIIpEo5BlUAANzgYjC9AAnuA4FJRaRmbdAXTQeCmbzbmzHk9hdzvlSaQS9LQAMxWmkcc5ciBa2GcIA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a discriminated union instead (but see below, there is an alterative using your current structure); then TypeScript can ensure that the object being provided has the necessary properties based on its `name`:

```
interface Circle {
    name: "Circle";
    radius: number;
}

interface Rectangle {
    name: "Rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

type Shape = Circle | Rectangle;

const shapes: Shape[] = [];

// These work:
shapes.push({ name: "Circle", radius: 12 });
shapes.push({ name: "Rectangle", width: 34, height: 56 });

// This causes an error: 
shapes.push({ name: "Rectangle", width: 34 });
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gKGSORDgFsIAuZAInUxxoG5Dio4ATYAVwGdqQ3MgCNoLAL758oSLEQoAShARg4IAOY5kBYiXJVaSlWs0RmrIgHdgHMAAsBQ0VBa67EYOrthHIsfkl8MABPAAcUAGU7OHDkAF40DGwUAB9kI1UNHBZ8BAB7EF4wZF5o8P5kKJiIAG0AXXjkepyAehbkABV3XhRLPKgAa0p8UureADpQvjsAClw9Cmo6JMYAGmR2Lj5qAEYAJmRxAEoWUfLJ6bmFgxoMkzXka1sHZABmABZ1909vagBWABshxOUjanTswF4yAQcD4EChamQ0Cg-WoIzK8IupSupEWhmUmVMNHWT3s1A+wKYQA)

Notice how the relationship between `Shape` and `Circle`/`Rectangle` is inverted: Now we derive `Shape` from `Circle`, `Rectangle`, and (down the line) other shapes. The `name` property in each of the shapes is a string literal property (it can only have the one value the shape defines for it for any given shape). When we create the union of shapes, `name` can be used to narrow members to specific shapes.

---

> Is there some other way than as Type to cast an object literal to a type inline as a parameter to a function that will do full type checking?

TypeScript doesn't have casting, it has type assertions. In languages that have casting, a cast can actually *modify* a value (for instance, you can use a cast to convert the actual bit values of an IEEE-754 floating point `double` into a 64-bit two's complement `int`). TypeScript doesn't have that. All that a type assertion does is tell TypeScript that **you**, the programmer, know that something fulfills the requirements of a given type.

But for what you're describing, TypeScript **just** added the [`satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/) which tells TypeScript you expect something to satisfy a type contract (without forcing it to). You *could* use it for this, but it's ugly:

```
// These work:
shapes.push({ name: "Circle", radius: 12 } satisfies Circle as Shape);
shapes.push({ name: "Rectangle", width: 34, height: 56 } satisfies Rectangle as Shape);

// This causes an error: 
shapes.push({ name: "Rectangle", width: 34 } satisfies Rectangle as Shape);
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAs4AcUG8CwAUMiciHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcRAvkUaJLIigDCwKAgA2KCAA9IIACZ00mHMgLFSUOHOABXOrRA6KAI2jtCXQj3DR4SZACUICMHBDMJyabIVLseIlJkAHdgOTB0AyNTKHMg9AhgZnQwKJMzTm5CCTB6ZQh9PxwAbQBdZABeZDLzIgB6OuQAFQS6FGCAeygAa2oiOny6ADosPXQAClwyShpkACJhUQk5gBpkTW09WgBGACZkDno4MGA6GGAC5EXxFDhFDH8ASnMB-2HRgcnpqlo5pxc3B4IKsQmEIrQAMwAFjWCSSKVoAFYAGwHI4nM4XRT-VzuTx3IoQZ5ZBrNdCnZAIOB6S5uLxQKBdWj9QYjMZfcg-eY4wHLNahcKRZDQtF0Y6nc6XHl4273fLEwhAA)

The `satisfies` triggers the type check. Then we need a type assertion because the objects are defined with inline object literals, triggering TypeScript's excess property checks. (You wouldn't need it if the objects weren't defined inline [[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAs4AcUG8CwAUMiciHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcRAvkUaJLIigDCwKAgA2KCAA9IIACZ00mHMgLFSUOHOABXOrRA6KAI2jtCXQj3DR4SZACUICMHBDMJyabIVLseIlJkAHdgOTB0AyNTKHMg9AhgZnQwKJMzTm5CCTB6ZQh9PxwAbQBdZABeZDLzIgB6OuQAFQS6FGCAeygAa2oiBA6QBmQEWmFRTyrcMkoaZAAicfEIeYAaZE1tPVoARgAmZA5zOny6ADosPXQACgQASnMBodyoHdonFzcPFCmZqlp5h9XO4JGsQmEIrQAMwAFnWCSSKVoAFYAGyHY6nC5Xa6vB5ZBrNdDARQIOB6ArINxeKBQLq0fqDYZQPbvZzA76VVR-OaA9lfUHrULhSLIWEYognfznS4nXF7fGEIA)], but doing it inline was one of your requirements.)

Comment: This is a great suggestion and I will use it. Thank you! I'd still like an answer to the actual question though

Comment: @samanthaj - I've written up how you could use the brand-new `satisfies` for this, but I don't think you'll like the ergonomics. :-D

Comment: Oh yes, the new "satisfies T as U" operator

Comment: @AndreaSimoneCosta - LOL Yeah, because they're literals, we can't just do `shapes.push({ name: "Rectangle", width: 34 } satisfies Rectangle);` since it triggers excess property checks. We could do `const r: Rectangle = { name: "Rectangle", width: 34 }; shapes.push(r);` but the OP specified "inline," so...

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully I'll never have to use `satisfies` :P